# Antd horizontal sub menu "floating"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a very simple antd menu which I used following their docs. However, when the submenu opens it is floating (not attached to the main menu) and it really doesn't look good.
How do I fix this?

This is what my code currently looks like:

```
export function MainMenu () {
  return (
    <AntdLayout>
      <Menu mode='horizontal' theme='dark' style={{ position: 'fixed', zIndex: 1, width: '100%', marginBottom: 100 }}>
        <Menu.Item key='home'>
          Home
        </Menu.Item>
        <SubMenu key='submenu' title='SubMenu'>
            <Menu.Item key='1'>
              Option 1
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key='2'>
              Option 2
            </Menu.Item>
        </SubMenu>
        <Menu.Item key='contact'>
          Contact
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
</AntdLayout>
  )
}
```

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As its not adviced because [Ant is a design system](https://ant.design/docs/spec/introduce), you can achieve it by targeting the `.ant-menu-submenu > .ant-menu` selectors:

```
/* ./App.css */
.ant-menu-submenu > .ant-menu {
  margin-top: -5px;
}

// index.js
import { Layout, Menu } from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './App.css';

function MainMenu() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Menu mode="horizontal" openKeys={['submenu']}>
        <Menu.Item key="home">Home</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.SubMenu
          key="submenu"
          title="SubMenu"
        >
          <Menu.Item key="1">Option 1</Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="2">Option 2</Menu.Item>
        </Menu.SubMenu>
        <Menu.Item key="contact">Contact</Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Q-58176474-SubMenuMarginTop]